# Windows Azure Blob

Tags: azure, blob, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've been trying to create a Windows Azure Blob containing an image file. I followed these tutorials: http://www.nickharris.net/2012/11/how-to-upload-an-image-to-windows-azure-storage-using-mobile-services/ and http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-dotnet/. Finally the following code represents a merging of them. On the last line, however, an exception is raised:

> An exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A binding for the specified type name was not
>   found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80132005)

Even the container is created the table, but It doesn't work properly.

```
private async void SendPicture()
{
    StorageFile media = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync("fanny.jpg");

    if (media != null)
    {
        //add todo item to trigger insert operation which returns item.SAS
        var todoItem = new Imagem()
        {
            ContainerName = "mypics",
            ResourceName = "Fanny",
            ImageUri = "uri"
        };
        await imagemTable.InsertAsync(todoItem);

        //Upload image direct to blob storage using SAS and the Storage Client library for Windows CTP
        //Get a stream of the image just taken
        using (var fileStream = await media.OpenStreamForReadAsync())
        {
            //Our credential for the upload is our SAS token
            StorageCredentials cred = new StorageCredentials(todoItem.SasQueryString);
            var imageUri = new Uri(todoItem.SasQueryString);

            // Instantiate a Blob store container based on the info in the returned item.
            CloudBlobContainer container = new CloudBlobContainer(
                    new Uri(string.Format("https://{0}/{1}",
                        imageUri.Host, todoItem.ContainerName)), cred);

            // Upload the new image as a BLOB from the stream.
            CloudBlockBlob blobFromSASCredential =
                    container.GetBlockBlobReference(todoItem.ResourceName);
            await blobFromSASCredential.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream.AsInputStream());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you tell on which line in your code you're getting the exception?

Comment: On:

await blobFromSASCredential.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream.AsInputStream());

Thank you Gaurav Mantri.

Answer (score 1):

Please use [Assembly Binding Log Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx) to see which load is failing. As also mentioned in the article, the common language runtime's failure to locate an assembly typically shows up as a TypeLoadException in your application.